# Relative paths in spring classpath resource

Tags: java, spring, url, path, relative-path

I have a bunch of spring config files, all of which live under the META-INF directory in various subpackages.  I have been using import like the following...

```
  <import resource="../database/schema.xml"/>
```

So a relative path from the source file.  This works fine when I am working with a local build outside of a jar file.  But when I package everything up in a jar then I get an error that it cannot resolve the URL resource.  If I change the above to an absolute path (with classpath:) then it works fine.

Is there any way to use relative paths with ".." in when the configs are packaged in a jar or am I restricted to descending relative paths and absolute paths only?

Answer (score 13):

A short addition: If you want to access the resources from a jar, it should read:

```
<import resource="classpath*:database/schema.xml"/>
```

Comment: The asterix! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

```
<import resource="classpath:database/schema.xml"/>
```

Comment: It would need to be <import resource="classpath:../database/schema.xml"/> but this doesn't work.

Comment: Hm... You have to have it in META-INF?

Comment: Not necessarily but I need it packaged in the jar so users of the jar pick up the config with it.

Comment: My structure for jars looks like so:
src/main/java/ - code
src/main/resources/ - configurations files (including spring)

Answer (score 4):

What works fine on my project is the following lines in the app-servlet.xml :

```
<!-- Database Configuration -->
<import resource="classpath*:/database/DataSource.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:/database/Hibernate.xml"/>
```

[image: Directories]

If it can help you ...