# Spring - relative path in classpath resource

Tags: java, spring, path, resources, relative-path

I'm wondering if if (and how) I could use relative classpath resource paths within spring. I've following application structure:

```
src/
  org/me/
    mainContext.xml
    app1/
      app1Context.xml
    app2/
      app2Context.xml
      comp1/
        comp1Context.xml
```

Now in `mainContext.xml` I'd like to import bean definitions by relative paths:

```
<import resource="classpath:app1/app1Context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:app2/app2Context.xml"/>
```

and similary in `app2Context.xml`:

```
<import resource="classpath:comp1/comp1Context.xml"/>
```

(The `org.me.app2` code is in different jar (`WEB-INF/lib/app2.jar`)).

However currently I'm getting FileNotFoundException exception:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app1/app1Context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Can I use such relative paths? How? To which path are relative classpath paths resolved?

There is a similar question ([Relative paths in spring classpath resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601106/relative-paths-in-spring-classpath-resource)) but people are only suggesting what I'm already doing (and what doesn't work right now).

Answer (score 1):

> There is a similar question ([Relative paths in spring classpath resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601106/relative-paths-in-spring-classpath-resource)) but people are only suggesting what I'm already doing (and what doesn't work right now).

That is wrong: The people answered with paths that are relative to the classpath root, but not relative to the location of the xml! (*You should notice that the example in "[Relative paths in spring classpath resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601106/relative-paths-in-spring-classpath-resource)" is a maven project, so the folder resources become the classpath root)

So if you want to use the same technique then the imports would be (with `org/me`):

```
<import resource="classpath:org/me/app1/app1Context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:org/me/app2/app2Context.xml"/>
```